# Erro ao dar post pelo Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Tenho uma tabela que só tem um registro essa tabela eu guardo os parâmetros do sistema ele só tem uma item gravado e o numero de item dela numa vai ser maior que 1 **logo ela não tem chave primaria**, só que quando tento alterar os parâmetros do sistema apresenta esse erro:

> Update command updated [0] instead of [1] record.
>   Possible reasons: update table does not have PK or row identifier, record has been changed/deleted by another user.

Possíveis razões: a tabela de atualização não possui PK ou identificador de linha, a gravação foi alterada / excluída por outro usuário.

A tabela não precisa de uma PK já que não se relaciona a outras e também não foi alterada por outro usuário  pois estou rodando ela localmente para testes. 
Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Os componentes ao qual você está utilizando para a manipulação dos dados, deve estar requerendo uma chave primária, mesmo que haja somente um registro na tabela, porquê não criar uma PK? Se você está utilizando "DataSetProvider", deve alterar a propriedade "UpdateMode" para "upWhereAll"

Comment: Não estou usando o `DataSetProvider` vou mudar as opções do componente de conexão para ver se funciona

Comment: Minha tabela usa três colunas como PK e estava dando esta mensagem. [SOLUÇÃO] A unica coisa que fiz foi altera no DataSource a propriedade KeyFields, adicionei as três colunas.

Comment: Verifique se seu campo onde está a chave primária, é o primeiro na tabela referida.
Isso aconteceu comigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisando mais achei isso no site [docwiki.embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Update_Command_Generation_(FireDAC))

O `UpdateOptions.UpdateMode` controla a geração da cláusula *WHERE* para publicar atualizações e exclusões. O valor padrão `upWhereKeyOnly` usa na frase *WHERE* apenas as colunas de identificação únicas e fornece uma maneira eficiente e segura de localizar a linha de atualização. Quando nenhuma coluna de identificação exclusiva é especificada e nenhuma coluna de identificação de linha é encontrada, FireDAC irá mudar UpdateOptions.UpdateMode para `upWhereAll`. Os seguintes campos incluídos na cláusula *WHERE* podem levar ao erro "sem linhas encontradas"

lá mostra as propriedades que terá que desabilitar para resolver esse Problema.

1. Fornecendo colunas de identificação únicas corretas;
2. Desabilitando alguns campos com o uso *WHERE* excluindo `pfInWhere` propriedade `TField.ProviderFlags` correspondente ;
3. Suprimindo esses erros configurando `UpdateOptions.CountUpdatedRecords` para **False**.

Answer (score 0):

Se isso não resolver. Acho que neste caso, você poderia usar um arquivo ini ao invés de uma tabela.
Geralmente utilizamos arquivo .ini para guardar paramentros do sistema, é bem eficaz.

Comment: Mais nesses parâmetros tem a senha e conta  do e-mail dos Clientes...

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia, passei por este problema agora, mas um colega de trabalho me ajudou a resolver.

O que realmente acontece nessa situação é que ele está sendo ***"setado"*** apenas o código da chave primária, então para alterar o campo necessário caso não seja a chave primária é só selecionar a **"TFDTable"** e ir em **"UpdateOptions > UpdateMode > Colocar: upWhereChanged ou upWhereAll"** e assim resolverá o que precisa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]